# How to add limit to array data fetched from database in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, arrayobject

I'm retrieving the rows from user table and I'm using below code.

```
<?php $user = User::get(); ?>
```

I want to add array limit for $user data. I don't want to use `paginate();`. To add limit I'm using below code but it's not working 

`$users = array_slice($users, 0,2);` 

But it's showing below error message

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_slice() expects
>   parameter 1 to be array, object given' in........

How to I add limit to `$user`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $user = User::get(); 
    $user = $user ->limit(10);
?>
```

try limit or

```
<?php 
    $user = User::get(); 
    $user = $user ->take(10);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent Laravel versions you can also use:

```
User::limit(10)->offset(0)->get();
```

Note that User model must extend Eloquent.

Comment: This is better answer as it already limits the result from the query so the result is simply what is needed not all users. You can also use `->take(10)->get()`

Comment: The `get` method is best, and should be, called after `where`, `limit`, `offset`, and everything for better resource management.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use:

```
$users = array_slice($user, 0,2);
```

Comment: array_slice would be good if `$user` is an array. Possibly converting it to an array first would do `$users = array_slice($user->toArray(), 0, 2);` but a better method would simply be `$users = $user->take(2);`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `$users` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#collections), not an array.

You could use the [take](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-take) method

```
$users = User::get()->take(3);
```

or the [slice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-slice) method

```
$users = User::get()->slice(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can achieve this.

Applying the offset and limit directly to the query builder allows you to fetch only the needed rows.

```
$users = User::skip(5)->take(10)->get();
$users = User::offset(5)->limit(10)->get();
```

If you insist on working with complete result, then this approach is what to you need. You need to use collection slice method not array_slice since the result is a collection.

```
$users = User::all();
// Collection slice(offset, limit)
$users = $users->slice(5, 10);
```